# Detail about google smart home "mode" trait

Tags: google-smart-home

I have a question about the device.trait "Modes"

I create a washer machine with traits Modes and the SYNC.response look like this

```
{
"requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
"payload": {
"agentUserId": "1836.15267389",
"devices": [
    {
        "id": "311_washer_1",
        "type": "action.devices.types.WASHER",
        "traits": ["action.devices.traits.Modes","action.devices.traits.OnOff"],
        "name": {
            "name": "Laboratory Washer 1",
            "nicknames": ["Laboratory Washer"]
        },
        "willReportState": false,
        "attributes":{
            "availableModes":[{
                "name": "speed",
                "name_values": [{
                    "name_synonym": ["speed"],
                    "lang": "en"
                }],
                "settings": [{
                        "setting_name": "fast",
                        "setting_values": [{
                            "setting_synonym": ["fast"],
                            "lang": "en"
                        }]
                    },{
                        "setting_name": "medium",
                        "setting_values":[{
                            "setting_synonym":["medium"],
                            "lang": "en"
                        }]
                    },{
                        "setting_name": "slow",
                        "setting_values":[{
                            "setting_synonym":["slow"],
                            "lang": "en"
                        }]
                    }
                ],
                "ordered": true
            }]
        }
    }
]
}
```

}

I have a mode call "speed"

but when I talk to the assistant, it just replay my that "That mode isn't available for it"

Can somebody tell me where is wrong or is it related to

> Currently, you must use the names in the example JSON; custom names are not yet supported.

in the [instruction page](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/modes#response)

Thank you~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For incorporating modes, there are only a specific set of available mode values and settings that you are able to use. Custom names and settings are currently not supported, so you need to stick to a specific list.

If you would like to get a new mode or settings added, you can [file an issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/new) on the GitHub sample and I'll add the specific values that you want.

In the meantime, here's an example that should work using current modes.

```
"availableModes":[{
    "name": "Cleaning Mode",
    "name_values": [{
        "name_synonym": ["cleaning mode"],
        "lang": "en"
    }],
    "settings": [{
        "setting_name": "High",
        "setting_values": [{
            "setting_synonym": ["high"],
            "lang": "en"
        }]
    },{
        "setting_name": "Medium",
        "setting_values":[{
            "setting_synonym":["medium"],
            "lang": "en"
        }]
    },{
        "setting_name": "Low",
        "setting_values":[{
            "setting_synonym":["low"],
            "lang": "en"
        }]
    }],
    "ordered": true
}]
```

Comment: So it means that the mode name is come from a pre-defined list, if that, where can I get that pre-defined list of mode name and settings?

Thank you very much~~

Comment: A full list is currently not available

Comment: So for now the most convenient way to add a new mode and settings is to file an issue on github right?

Comment: Yes, that's currently the best process at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much